# Duplicate Key when inserting into a SQL database from C# code

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm adding features to a program that was originally written by another programmer and now I've run into this dilemma. When I send the database this query,

```
INSERT INTO AQS_STATION_Road_Influences (STA_SerialCode,
TangentStreetNumber, TangentStreetName, RoadTypeCode,
TrafficCountValue, TrafficCountYear, DirectionToStreetCode,
TrafficCountSourceCode) Values (4, '45', '56', '3', '365', '2016',
'NE', '54'),  (141, '45', '56', '3', '365', '2016', 'NE', '54')
```

I get

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AQS_STATION_Road_Influences'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.AQS_STATION_Road_Influences'. The duplicate key value is (4, 45).
>
> The statement has been terminated.

I've checked the table in the query it has no such primary key. When I do a select * from the table I get the 3 entries that I manually put in there. Which are as follows:

[These are the current rows in the road influences table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX3fn.png)

The primary key for this table is a composite one which consists of `STA_SerialCode` and `TangentStreetNumber`. The confusing factor about this is that if I paste my insert query directly into SQL manager it runs just fine. I've tried running the insert one row at a time but it still threw the same error. I've also stepped through my code to ensure that the query I think is being passed is actually the one I want. For reference's sake this is the C# code I think is relevant:

```
public int DbUpdateTable(string strQuery, DataTable dtData)
        {
            int nRows;

            try
            {
                DbProviderFactory factoryProvider = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(_strDbProvider);
                using (DbConnection connDb = factoryProvider.CreateConnection())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        connDb.ConnectionString = _strDbConnection;
                        connDb.Open();

                        using (DbTransaction dbTrans = connDb.BeginTransaction())
                        {
                            using (DbDataAdapter adapterDb = factoryProvider.CreateDataAdapter())
                            {
                                using (DbCommand cmdDb = connDb.CreateCommand())
                                {
                                    cmdDb.Transaction = dbTrans;
                                    cmdDb.CommandText = strQuery;

                                    if (strQuery.Contains("INSERT INTO"))
                                    {
                                        adapterDb.InsertCommand = cmdDb;
                                    }
                                    else if (strQuery.Contains("DELETE FROM"))
                                    {
                                        adapterDb.DeleteCommand = cmdDb;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        adapterDb.SelectCommand = cmdDb;
                                    }

                                    using (DbCommandBuilder bldDb = factoryProvider.CreateCommandBuilder())
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            bldDb.DataAdapter = adapterDb;
                                            nRows = adapterDb.Update(dtData);
                                            dbTrans.Commit();
                                            return (nRows);
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception dbex)//DbException dbex)
                                        {
                                            Debug.Assert(false);
                                            dbTrans.Rollback();
                                            throw new Exception(dbex.Message);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (DbException ex)
                    {
                        Debug.Assert(false);
                        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (connDb.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                        {
                            connDb.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Assert(false);
                Trace.WriteLine("Excpt: " + e.Message, this.ToString());
                throw new CybernetException("QUERY ERROR: " + strQuery);
            }
            finally
            {
            }

        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
For an easier read, I'm adding the primary key SQL code from my comment in here.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AQS_STATION_Road_Influences] ADD CONSTRAINT
[PK_AQS_STATION_Road_Influences] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
[STA_SerialCode] ASC, [TangentStreetNumber] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX =
OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] GO
```

**EDIT 2:**

[SQL Profiler displaying what appears to be two sent queries.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2IO5.png)

Comment: Does that constraint 'PK_AQS_STATION_Road_Influences' exist under the constraints folder in this table when you view it in Management Studio?  You may need to check to see how it is configured.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend passing in SQL in the way you do, instead use stored procedures and split out your functionality to determine the type of query. Also, do not throw a new exception since you lose the stacktrace. Instead just use `throw`. Finally, make sure you are looking at the right database.

Comment: are you sure your application is pointing to the same database that you're connected to in SSMS?

Comment: No, the constraint was added at the table's design time. When I right-click on the key and send it to a query window this is what I get: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AQS_STATION_Road_Influences] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_AQS_STATION_Road_Influences] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [STA_SerialCode] ASC,
 [TangentStreetNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: @Kritner yes, it's pointing to the same database/table, because if I run it a second time with only the second row the query runs successfully

Comment: @user1666620 As I've said, this is not my code originally and fixing the try catch throws or other specific functionality of this code is fairly low on my list. Personally I would have written this differently but I didn't have the luxury.

Comment: @dcfyj I don't follow your last comment regarding "if I run it a second time with only the second row the query runs successfully". Can you be more clear as to what this means? How does it relate to you knowing you are looking at the same database the application is attempting to insert data into?

Comment: @user1666620 The table in question only exists in a single database as I'm the one that created it. I haven't added to other databases as yet since it's currently not working correctly

Comment: @dcfyj and the application is 100% not connecting to another database on the network? There is no other database mentioned in the config?

Comment: @user1666620 There are other databases in the application, but if it were trying to connect to another database I wouldn't be getting a primary key error because the table I'm inserting into doesn't exist on any database but this one.

Comment: I would run SQL Profiler or similar and see the actual SQL-statements sent from the application

Comment: @DanielStackenland Just ran it. SQL Profiler says the program is sending the insert query it's supposed to send.

Comment: Is it possible that your method gets called more than once, attempting the same INSERT a second time? Or maybe the data table parameter holds a duplicate row?

Comment: @Biscuits I have a breakpoint in the function and it errors out the first time through so the table never gets a new row inserted. Checked the data table, all its rows are unique.

Comment: Does the PrimaryKey property in the DataTable object passed match the PK in the DB? Does that table have any triggers?

Comment: @Diego The table in the code doesn't appear to have any primaryKey anything, I'll look into it more tomorrow (about to get off work). As for triggers I didn't make any triggers for the table when I created it.

Comment: And the profiler showed it was only called once? Did you copy the SQL-statement from the profiler to SQLmanager and run it?

Comment: @DanielStackenland It appears to be calling it twice, I'll paste a picture link in my question for you to see. I didn't copy/paste into manager because I saw no difference between what it got and what I but I'll go ahead and do that just in case.

Comment: So I did as Diego and Daniel suggested. I set the primary key for the datatable but it did nothing for me, the error still happened and pasting into sql manager from sql profiler gave me no new information.

Comment: But, now when you showed us the insert statement is sent twice you have to go back to the code and try to figure out why it's making two calls...

Comment: Try to comment out the Commit. As far as I know, the ".update" already takes care of it. Further more, if you use a binding source in C#, remember to end the edit mode before executing the .update.

Comment: @DanielStackenland I'v been trying to hunt it down, it seems to send both on the nRows = adapterDb.Update(dtData); line.

Comment: @Rene Commenting out the commit would do no good as the code doesn't make it that far, it throws the duplicate key exception on the update line. While there is a binding source on this form it isn't part of this table, so I don't think it would affect it but I'll look into it.

Comment: Im not sure but it could be that use both the DbCommandBuilder (bldDb) and set the command properties on the DataAdapter, maybe try remove the commandBuilder?

Comment: @DanielStackenland I'm not even sure if its doing anything, but removing the CommandBuilder didn't help, sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after looking for a few days and still being unable to figure out why the insert query was being sent twice, I ended up just rewriting the function and now it works just fine.

```
public int SimpleDBUpdateTable(string strQuery)
    {
        int nRows;

        try
        {
            DbProviderFactory factoryProvider = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(_strDbProvider);
            using (DbConnection connDb = factoryProvider.CreateConnection())
            {
                try
                {
                    connDb.ConnectionString = _strDbConnection;
                    connDb.Open();
                    using (DbCommand cmdDb = connDb.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmdDb.CommandText = strQuery;
                        nRows = cmdDb.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        return nRows;
                    }
                }
                catch (DbException ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (connDb.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        connDb.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I'm guessing the duplication had something to do with the adapter and the command object, but as I said, I couldn't find the reason.